# Facebook - problems with "august_2012" platform migration

Tags: facebook

I am getting this warning message in an iOS app using FB auth:

`ERROR:This endpoint has been deprecated.To temporarily reenable it,you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration. It will be disable permanently on August 1,2012.`

The issue is to disable that migration for now. But, it was already disabled, so not sure how to fix this quickly - as opposed to updating the app and pushing it back out to the store which we will do.

Comment: Where do you disable this setting? Did you solve this problem already?

Comment: We have not solved it - but the setting is in the Facebook admin for the app.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I solved it by using the newest ShareKit!! Works now perfect again!

Comment: @NicTesla, where are you downloading new version from? is it 0.2.1? An example project given with that code also have the same issue...

Comment: The last news about the issue at [the facebook help center](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=2334078)

Comment: @Paresh: I downloaded it from GitHub (https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) but the same version is also avaliable on the official website (http://getsharekit.com/install/). I'll write an answer about how i solved it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the newest ShareKit Version (0.2.1), which I downloaded from [GitHut](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) but the same version is also avaliable on [getsharekit.com/install](http://getsharekit.com/install/).

Next i added the folder "ShareKit" located in "Classes" by drag&dropping in my XCode project (as usual).

For safety reasons, the previouse configuration file has been changed into a class. Set the configuration data for the sharingservices (FB, Twitter,...) in the class "DefaultSHKConfigurator.m". (Btw. I subclassed the DefaultSHKConfigurator so i still have the original structure)

To setup FB, change the settings:

```
- (NSString*)facebookAppId {
return @"..."; //app-id from facebook (create fb-app first, if not already done)
}

- (NSString*)facebookLocalAppId {
    return @"";
}
```

Than in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: Method, set the ShareKonfiguration.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[DefaultSHKConfigurator alloc] init];

[SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];

[configurator release];

//init the rest
..
}
```

After that, add an URL Scheme (in XCode 4.x select your project, select one target, click "Add"->"Add URL Type") and set the URL Scheme to "fb+your fb-app id" (mine looked like "fb35486..").

To let FB open your app and the user is immeditly able to post content, add

```
- (void) openFBWithURL:(NSURL*) URL {

if (URL != nil) {

    NSString* scheme = [URL scheme];

    NSString* prefix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb%@", SHKCONFIG(facebookAppId)];

        if ([scheme hasPrefix:prefix]) {

            [SHKFacebook handleOpenURL:URL];
    }
}
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

        [self openFBWithURL:url];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

        [self openFBWithURL:url];

    return YES;
}
```

Than it should be setup and ready for use.